# How to draw line on Linear Layout?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How can I draw line on `LinearLayout`? I searched and I didn't found answer ;/ I know how can I draw this line on `EditView` and `TextView` but not `LinearLayout`, maybe isn't it possible?

I tried create new view (horizontal_line) and add to my `LinearLayout` but it was wrong idea.

Comment: extend LinearLayout and override dispatchDraw

Comment: in axml or C#. It's a Xamarin.

Comment: what type of line you want..is it horizontal line? is it boundry line? is it the line in the midlle?? explain your quesiton properly

Comment: I need 1px horizontal line, which I can dynamic set (height position) on my linear layout in adapter code

Comment: extend LinearLayout and
override dispatchDraw

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
 <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_height="0.5dip"
android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
android:background="#E6E6E6"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view in Xaml,it creates a vertical line so you would need to change the height and width

```
<View
 android:id="@+id/verticalSeparator"
 android:layout_width="1dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If targeting Honeycomb or later, you can use the `setShowDividers()` and `setDividerDrawable()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use Xaml and just c#
There the answer :

```
LinearLayout scrollContainer = new LinearLayout(Application.Context);
scrollContainer.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

View line = new View(Application.Context);
line.Id = 1;
line.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.DarkGray); // the color you want
line.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 2); // 2 is the height you want
scrollContainer.AddView(line);
```